# Can somebody recommend any task + workflow management engine?

Tags: open-source, workflow, bpmn

Does somebody know any good open source (ideally free) task + workflow management engine (library, framework)? Maybe something like activity.org.

Preferably with: organization structure (hierarchy) management, collaboration work, document workflows. Ideally with implementation of BPMN/BPEL.

Based on Ruby (ideally), Java, PHP. Or maybe does somebody know any plugins with this functionality (say for Redmine, Trac)?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may have a look on some opensource BPEL alternatives like;

1. [WSO2 BPS](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server/). You can find more information [here](http://wso2.org/project/bps/2.1.2/docs/index.html).
2. [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look to Bonita Open Solution from bonitasoft.

It is an BPMN 2.0 implementation in JAVA. It comes with a studio to design your processes, an engine to manage the execution of the processes you designed and the user experience, some kind of portal to manage your processes, see tasks assigned to users, ...
BOS comes with a user directory where a user can have one or several roles in different groups so I think it may answer to your needs.

Concerning the language, it has been written in Java but it could be integrated in an external application written in the language you want. I have for example integrated it in a C# application as in a PHP application.

Concerning the PHP application, I've written an article on the subject a few mounth ago here : 
http://community.bonitasoft.com/blog/how-integrate-bos-engine-php-application

If you need more information, feel free to ask :)

Cheers